# Alternative to mhash_keygen_s2k()

Tags: php, hash, mcrypt, s2k, mhash

The [`mcrypt_encrypt` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) says that:

> **It is recommended to use the `mhash` functions to create a key from a string.**

But the [introduction of the `mhash`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mhash.php) manual says that:

> **Note:** This extension is obsoleted by Hash.

However, the closest thing I could find to the rather useful [`mhash_keygen_s2k()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mhash-keygen-s2k.php) function was the [`hash_pbkdf2()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) function. However, I'm not even sure if it fits the job since it only exists in the SVN.

So, can I rely on the `mhash` extension, or it will eventually become deprecated and dropped? If so, is there any alternative built-in function or do I have to implement the Salted S2K algorithm myself?

Comment: Bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63250 submitted.

Comment: You can also check the answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965708/php-hash-pbkdf2-function as one of then includes the PHP of a PBKDF2 implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up peeking into mhash source code porting this to PHP:

```
function keygen_s2k($hash, $password, $salt, $bytes)
{
    $result = false;

    if (extension_loaded('hash') === true)
    {
        foreach (range(0, ceil($bytes / strlen(hash($hash, null, true))) - 1) as $i)
        {
            $result .= hash($hash, str_repeat("\0", $i) . str_pad(substr($salt, 0, 8), 8, "\0", STR_PAD_RIGHT) . $password, true);
        }

        $result = substr($result, 0, intval($bytes));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If anyone knows any alternative built-in function, I would still like to hear about it.